# Novice Javascript query about bad input

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple tip calculator to help myself learn Javascript. The problem I can't solve is how to compensate for "bad input".

In the code below if the user prefaces the numeric input amount with a dollar sign `$`, the result is `NAN`.

```
function tipAmount(){
var dinner=prompt("How much was dinner?");
result = dinner*.10;

alert("Your tip is " +"$"+result );

}
```

How do I fix that.

Comment: How do you *want* to handle it?

Comment: My question is doubling as a way to pry for options as to what is possible.So other than "as simple as possible" I simply don't know.

Comment: Oh wait. I see what you mean. I want the $ to be ignored!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to parse out the numeric value with a regular expression:

```
var match = dinner.match(/\d+\.?\d*/); // parse with a regular expression

if(!match) { // not able to parse
    alert("wrong");
}

var price = +match[0]; // convert to a number

result = price * .10;
```

The regular expression `/\d+\.?\d*/` means: one or more digits, and possibly a dot with other digits following. This means that if e.g. `dinner` is `"$1.23"`, `price` will be the number `1.23`. The same goes for `"$ 1.23"` or `"1.23 dollar"` etc - the number will be parsed out with the pattern defined by the regular expression.

Comment: shouldn't it be  `/\d*\.?\d*/` so you could type in `.5`

Comment: @Adam Rackis: You're correct, but then everything is optional and it will match nothing (`""` at the very beginning will already match).

Comment: ahhh - you've done this before... - handling that would be a pain.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: Well - I just noticed that side effect :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to parse the input into a float, and see if NaN is returned.

```
if (isNaN(parseFloat(dinner)))
    alert("Bad Input")
```

Just note that `45.2WWW`  will return 45.2, and so the above will pass.

If you want to make sure what the user typed in is exactly a number, you could do something like this:

```
var str = '3.445';
var num = parseFloat(str);

if (isNaN(num) || str.length !== num.toString().length)
     alert("Bad Input");
```

Answer (score 1):

try to parse the input as float or integer depending on your needs:

```
var dinner = parseFloat(prompt("How much was dinner?"));
```

or

```
var dinner = parseInt(prompt("How much was dinner?"));
```

this functions return 0 whether they unable to parse the input as number

Answer (score 1):

Given your approach of using alerts, the following will work:

```
function tipAmount() {
    var dinner=prompt("How much was dinner?");

    //convert "dinner" to a number, stripping out any non numeric data
    dinner = Number(dinner.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

    //any unknown data will convert to 0
    if(dinner <= 0) {
        alert("Please enter a valid amount");
        return false;
    }
    var result = dinner*.10;
    alert("Your tip is " +"$"+result );

    return true;
}
```

Please tip more!

Comment: Nitpicking, but you can replace `0-9` with `\d` (digit) and the `.` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: @pimvdb indeed. He could happily substitute the regular expression given in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: The conversion of the string to a number and removing the other characters is what I was looking for. Not understanding the syntax to achieve that is what I was itching to find an understand of. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the value is numeric - Javascript's isNaN:

```
if (isNaN(dinner)) {
    alert('Bad number, bub.');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you want to allow users to type in both - just number or an amount with $ at the beginning, you can check for first char:

```
if( dinner.charAt(0) == '$' )
{
    dinner = dinner.substring(1);
}
```

This way, whenever user types $, your app will just remove it. If they type a normal number it will calculate the tip for you...